# Confused about linearity of the differential

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be differentiable at  $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus, there exists a unique linear map $df_p$ satisfying
$$
\lim_{\| h\|\to 0} \frac{\| f(p + h) - f(p) - df_p(h)\|}{\| h\|}
$$

We call $df_p$ the differential of $f$ at $p$.

However, I'm confused: derivatives aren't necessary linear. For example, the derivative of $f(x) = 3x^3$ is $f'(x) = x^2$.

I'm unsure where my misunderstanding is? If $f$ is differentiable everywhere, then wouldn't
$f'(p) = df_p(p)$?

Comment: The differential is not the derivative.  The differential is a linear map which "approximates" the function $f$ at a point $p$ (for a suitable understanding of what "approximate" means).

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable, then $$df_p:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, v \mapsto f'(p) v.$$

Comment: What does $df_p$ satisfy?  I think you are missing half of an equation.

Comment: @JosephCamacho it satisfies that the limit below it approaches $0$

Comment: I think you are missing what "linear" means.  It does not mean that $df$ is a linear function.  It means that $d(f+g) = df + dg$

Comment: @SeverinSchraven That makes a little more sense, especially since I just read about the differential's relation to matrices. But I'm still confused. Also, another thing, if I'm given an arbitrary (not necessarily differentiable) function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ and am told to find the differential $df$, what does this mean? Classes just started and we only talked about the differential at a point, i.e., $df_p$, but I'm asked to find $df$ of functions such as $f$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfying $f(x) = \lvert x\rvert$.

Comment: If the function in question is not differentiable, then the usual differential does not exist (there are generalizations, but let us not go there). The differential $df$ is a function that associates to every point $p$ in the domain of $f$ the linear map $df_p$. This means $$df:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m), p \mapsto df_p.$$ Note that $df$ needs not to be linear, only $df_p$ has to be linear.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ok, this makes a lot more sense and I think I now better understand the differential (due to your comments and the 1 answer on my post). Would it then make sense to calculate the differential $df: \mathbb{R}^n - \{0\} \to \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^m)$ if $f$ is differentiable everywhere except $0$?

Comment: Absolutely, restricting the domain to the set of differentiable points will work.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the terms "derivative" and "derivative at a point". That is, let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\, x\mapsto x^3$, then clearly the derivative, the map $x\mapsto 3x^2$, is not linear. However the differential at a point $x_0$, what is the map $d f_{x_0}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R},\, t\mapsto f'(x_0)\cdot t$ is linear, as it is just the multiplication of $t$ by the constant $f'(x_0)=3x_{0}^2$.

The same happens in Euclidean spaces of higher dimensions, Banach spaces or smooth manifolds: the differential at a point of a differentiable map is a linear map. Indeed the definition of differential at a point imposes the condition to be linear!

That is, if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ then the differential of $f$ at $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, if exists, is the unique linear map $A: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that

$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-Ah\|}{\|h\|}=0
$$

and we use the notation $df_{x}$ instead of $A$. Also, for derivatives between Banach spaces, other notations can be used as $Df(x)$ or $\partial f(x)$. The point is that there $x$ is fixed, and the map is defined as $v\mapsto df_x v$ (or $v\mapsto \partial f(x)v$).